# If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $A\cap (B\Delta C)=(A\cap B) \Delta (A\cap C) $(, where $\Delta $ is the symmetric differences i.e $A$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If $A,B,C$ are three sets then prove that $A\cap (B\Delta C)=(A\cap B) \Delta (A\cap C) $(, where $\Delta $  is the symmetric differences i.e $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$)

If we try to solve it by expansion (i.e by writing it in $A\Delta B=(A-B)\cup (B-A)$ form )it  becomes a huge lengthy expression . Is that the only way? Can it be proved like that? I am not quite been able to solve it in that approach either. Is there any other way to solve it?

Comment: You can draw a Venn diagram.

Comment: @Lelouch Thanks! But I am looking for a more general approach.....

Comment: By logical sentences...

Comment: Element chase.   Or decompose it into the 8 partitions of the universal set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this an acceptable solution?:

$\begin{align}
x\in A\cap(B\Delta C)&\iff x\in A \text{ and } (x\in B \text{ or } x\in C \text{ but not both })\\
&\iff x\in A\cap B \text{ or } x\in A\cap C \text{ but not both }\\
&\iff x\in (A\cap B)\Delta (A\cap C)
\end{align}$

Comment: ...Thank you so much! I do get it now!...

Answer (score 1):

Use the characteristic functions: $$\chi_A(\chi_B+\chi_C-2\chi_B\chi C) \overset{?}{=} \chi_A\chi_B+\chi_A\chi_C-2\chi_A\chi_B\chi_A\chi_c$$
Seems like an identity, isn't it ?  See https://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0707/0707.2969.pdf